# How do you enable static content in the development server for a packaged django app?

Tags: django

I'm having trouble getting the static content to load from a django django app I've packaged.  I packaged my Django app according to the documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/reusable-apps/

I created a distribution

```
python ./setup.py sdist
```

I copied the distribution tarball to a remote server, extracted, and installed it

```
python ./setup.py install
```

I started the development server from the command line:

```
python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The templates are all loading properly, and they contain the correct data, but all the .css and .js files are failing to load with 404 errors.   When I look inside the .egg file created by sdist, the static contents are there.

Here is my settings.py:

```
# Django settings for django_grm project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'data.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '...'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_grm.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_grm.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'dj_grm',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Here's some of the output:

```
[17/Jun/2013 17:10:50] "GET /static/css/themes/tablesorter_grm/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1713
[17/Jun/2013 17:10:50] "GET /static/js/jquery-latest.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1662
[17/Jun/2013 17:10:50] "GET /static/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1689
[17/Jun/2013 17:10:50] "GET /static/js/tt_image.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1647
[17/Jun/2013 17:10:50] "GET /static/js/tt_text.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1644
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put your media into a `static/<app name>` directory in your app, so if your app is called `combobulator`, you'd put the static files into `combobulator/static/combobulator`.  The `collectstatic` management command will add your nested `combobulator` and its contents to the static root of the project that uses it. At that point, you just need to peek at the static files docs, pertaining to serving the files (local dev and Nginx, etc.)

Comment: In the packaging doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/reusable-apps/) they called for a slightly different directory structure:   app_name/static/<stuff>.  I experimented with your approach, but when I ran collectstatic I only saw the files being copied for the admin app.

Comment: @TravisBear - You might have made a mistake in your naming. I just tested it out, and directories were collected as well as files. The reason for nesting an extra `<app name>` directory (of course replace `<app name>` with your app name) is because `collectstatic` overwrites files and if you have something like `styles.css` in two different apps, you'll end up overwriting one with the other. So, `/myapp/static/myapp/[files here]` will results in the nested `myapp` directory and its files being collected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `collecstatic` method?

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add one change I made to orokusaki's answer.  I changed the way I was installing the package.  I switched from using `setup.py install` to `pip install <package>.tar.gz`.  This changes allowed collectstatic to find all the files, the rest was easy.